# Is there a closed nowhere dense set with no isolated points from the left?

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, cantor-set

I want to find an example (or the insight that there is no such set) of closed nowhere set with no isolated points from the left. I tried to write down some constructions of which I wasn't able to show closedness, for example the naive construction $A := \cup_k A_k$ with $A_0 := \{1\}$ and

$$A_k := \bigcup_{a\in A_{k-1}} \{a\}\cup \{a - \frac 1 n : n\in \Bbb N\}$$

Without the restriction of isolation from the left a good example would be of course the cantor set $C$ which is known to be closed and to not contain isolated points. But for example $\frac 2 3 \in C$ but $( 2/3 - 1/6 , 2/3 ) \cap C = \emptyset$. Thus $2/3$ is isolated from the left.

It seems not so easy how to adapt the cantor set construction to this problem. But I am not really experienced with this type of problems. Moreover, this appears to me as already known somewhere. A sufficient reference would be also an answer to my question.

Comment: What about a closed interval? Or just $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: So $x \in A$ is "isolated from the left" if there is some $r>0$ such that $(x-r,x) \cap A=\emptyset$?

Comment: I forgot to add "nowhere dense". Yes, this is meant by isolated from the left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The empty set works.  It is nowhere dense and has no points at all; in particular it has no points isolated from the left.

Now suppose $C \subseteq \mathbb R$ is nonempty closed and nowhere dense in $\mathbb R$.  There is a point $a \in C$.  Then $C_L := (-\infty , a)\setminus C$ is open.  $C$ is nowhere dense, so $C_L \ne \varnothing$.

An open set is the disjoint union of a countable family of open intervals.  So:

There exist $-\infty \le b < c \le a$ with $(b,c)$ a maximal interval in $C_L$, and therefore $(b,c)$ is disjoint from $C$.  Then (by maximality) $c \in C$ so it is isolated from the left.

Comment: First of all thanks for also providing a non-trivial answer. Do you mean by maximality that $b-c$ is maximal?
And if so, wouldn't it be enough to take $x\in C_L$ and take $(b,c) := \cup_{x \in I \subseteq C_L \text{open interval}} I$?

Comment: By "maximial" I mean that $(b,c)$ is not  proper subset of any open interval of $C_L$.